# There has been an error processing your request - could not read auth.json (composer issue)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, composer, git

I can still access my website through its domain but when I try to access the admin panel, it asks for my login but as soon as I login I receive the error:

```
There has been an error processing your request
```

I installed composer yesterday and tried to install git and it failed and have been stuck since. The full report is:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:304:"Could not read /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/auth.json

Warning: file_get_contents(/media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/auth.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php on line 92";i:1;s:7599:"#0 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php(289): Composer\Json\JsonFile->read()
#1 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php(532): Composer\Factory->createComposer(Object(Composer\IO\BufferIO), Array, false)
#2 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerFactory.php(47): Composer\Factory::create(Object(Composer\IO\BufferIO), '/media/share1/m...')
#3 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(362): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerFactory->create()
#4 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(375): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getComposer()
#5 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Composer/ComposerInformation.php(242): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getLocker()
#6 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/App/ProductMetadata.php(104): Magento\Framework\Composer\ComposerInformation->getSystemPackages()
#7 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/App/ProductMetadata.php(65): Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata->getSystemPackageVersion()
#8 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-admin-notification/Model/Feed.php(208): Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata->getVersion()
#9 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-admin-notification/Model/Feed.php(138): Magento\AdminNotification\Model\Feed->getFeedData()
#10 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-admin-notification/Observer/PredispatchAdminActionControllerObserver.php(51): Magento\AdminNotification\Model\Feed->checkUpdate()
#11 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Magento\AdminNotification\Observer\PredispatchAdminActionControllerObserver->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#12 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\AdminNotification\Observer\PredispatchAdminActionControllerObserver), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#13 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#14 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('controller_acti...', Array)
#15 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(91): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('controller_acti...', Array)
#16 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#19 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#20 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Backend...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#23 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#26 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#29 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#30 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#33 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#35 /media/share1/magento2/www.website.co.uk/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#36 {main}";s:3:"url";s:101:"/admin_otl1rg/admin/index/index/key/6e3c9e029bb08c2d16e6ed0ef005a5a57d0699964d272d75cb2c9176073fbe75/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Does anyone know how I can regain access to the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

Think I have figured it out. I SSH'd onto the machine hosting the website and sudo deleted auth.json and I seem to be able to access the admin panel again.